# How to save the url in a cookie then open the url from the cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, session, redirect, cookies

How to create 2 buttons. one 'save this page', second 'open saved page' button.
'save this page' button will store the current url of that page. while, 'open saved page' button will redirect user back to the save this page.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Documentation on [**HTML Button**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button) and [**JavaScript Eventbinding**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [**Cookies**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) and [**Window Location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) ► That should help you get started. Feel free to post your code if you are having trouble with it. Also check SO FAQ on [**How To Ask a Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
$(document).on('click', '[save page button class]', function () {
    $.cookie("SavedPageURL", "(Your URL here)");
});

$(document).on('click', '[open saved page button class]', function () {
    window.location.href = $.cookie("SavedPageURL");
});
```

You need to include jquery cookie js file for this.

Comment: is there anything wrong with this code??

Comment: Thanks Himanshu Vohra, do i have to put this code on both page?

Comment: @lien you need to put the first click event on the page where u want to save the URL to the cookie and the second click event on the page where you want to redirect to the other page.

Comment: Not sure why your comment is down voted. you got it right. Thanks mate!

Comment: Btw it work with https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie but not with this https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie. do you know why?

Comment: @lien I think the second one from "js-cookie" is a javascript one and the "carhartl" provides the jQuery one and in the code I used the jquery for saving the cookie.